# Add two datetime columns and divide result by 2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If actual `start date != ‘’` and `complete date != ''` calculate the `mid trim date = (actual start date + complete date)/2`

My table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AR_Placebook]
(
    [Region] nvarchar(255) NULL,
    [Network Area Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Substation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Circuit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Original (O) or Added Circuit (A)] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OC] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Line Miles] [float] NULL,
    [Line Miles Complete] [float] NULL,
    [Percent Complete] [float] NULL,
    [Contractor] [float] NULL,
    [Final Circuit Performance Audit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Should Be Billed] [float] NULL,
    [Invoiced to Date] [float] NULL,
    [Gap in Billing Difference] [float] NULL,
    [VCKT Number] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Bid Cost ] [float] NULL,
    [Bid Cost per Line Mile] [float] NULL,
    [Predictive Dialer Start Date] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ESTIMATED TRIM QUARTER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Actual Start Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Complete Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [MidTrimDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

I have tried this

```
 DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
       ,@EndTime   DATETIME 
       DECLARE @TotalWorkingHours varchar(50)
Declare @HalfDayCalculate varchar(50)
Declare @DivdeWorkingHours int
set @DivdeWorkingHours=2   

SELECT @TotalWorkingHours = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartTime, @EndTime),0), 108) 
from AR_Placebook
where @StartTime=[Actual Start Date] and 
      @EndTime =[Complete Date] and 
      [Actual Start Date]!='' and 
      [Complete Date]!='' 

set @HalfDayCalculate = convert(TIME(0), dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, @TotalWorkingHours) / @DivdeWorkingHours,  0),108)
select @HalfDayCalculate as MidTrimDate
```

Comment: You want time difference?

Comment: please include some sample data and expected result

Comment: @NayanishDamania thank you for your response i need both date and time difference in midtrimdate column

Comment: @Squirrel if [actual satrt  date] =2019-01-26 00:00:00.000 and [complete date] = 2019-08-24 00:00:00.000 then difference of above datetime  and divide the result by 2

Comment: please edit your question and include the information

Answer (score 1):

You can go with different approach - calculate the date difference between the two dates using `DATEDIFF` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), divide the result of the `DATEDIFF` by 2 and subtract this value from the complete date.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the answer as per your requirement.

SELECT [start date],DATEADD(DAY,day_difference,[start date]) AS [mid_date],[complete date],day_difference
FROM
(
SELECT '2020-03-01' AS[start date], '2020-03-20' AS[complete date],DATEDIFF(DAY,'2020-03-01' ,'2020-03-20')/2  as day_difference
)A

Also, find below snap.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xgym.png)

Answer (score 0):

> If actual start date != ‘’ and complete date != '' calculate the mid trim date = (actual start date + complete date)/2

I think you are looking for.  For the middle *day*:

```
select dateadd(day,
               datediff(day, start_date, complete_date) / 2,
               start_date
              )
```

If there is a time component, use a smaller time unit:

```
select dateadd(second,
               datediff(second, start_date, complete_date) / 2,
               start_date
              )
```